# ISO Standard relative to FHIR framework

Tags: hl7-fhir

In order to implement an FHIR based system for exchanging patient data, I would know if there is an ISO standard that could be applied to my project ?

I know that HL7 Version 3 is standardized with ISO/HL7 21731.
Is this the same thing for HL7 FHIR ? IE Would an FHIR based system be automatically ISO/HL7 21731 compliant ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not the same thing. No, a FHIR based system would not automatically be 21731 compliant. FHIR has not yet been brought to ISO - it will be a number of years before it becomes time to do that

If all you're looking for is a tick in the box to meet legal requirements, you might get away with claiming that a FHIR based system is 21731 compliant